# Mobile Safari - Notification Center pull down or Control Bar pull up detection

Tags: javascript, ios, html

I am creating a audio control bar for live audio streaming. When audio is streaming and the user pulls down the notification center (ios5+) or pulls up the control center (ios 7+) the audio pauses and plays back after user releases the notification/control center back to its original position. Though the audio plays back, there is no javascript even fired. Due to this i am unable to change the status from paused to playing. I tried on the event listener and object possible in the audio tag element. Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: Hm, very strange. `window.onblur` almost never fires on iOS... even when switching tabs. I'm curious to see the working solution

Comment: try visibilitychange,webkitvisibilitychange,window.onpageshow,window.onpagehide *ios7

Comment: i tried visibilitychange, webkitvisibilitychange, pageshow, pagehide, focus, blur, focusin, focusout nothing works. Page Visibility API in Mobile Safari iOS 7 is not working at all. Always it returns visibilityState as visible even though i have minimised the browser or locked my screen.